# Why do electric generators need a prime mover?

Tags: electromagnetism

Commonly electric generators need a mechanical torque provided by a prime mover [gas turbine or steam turbine or diesel engine,etc] which is needed for the rotation of the generator rotor. I would like to know why:-
1. The torque cannot be given directly to the generator rotor provided it can be designed to handle the working medium.
2. An air gap is provided between the rotor and stator --> why not vacuum?
3. An electromagnetic torque cannot be given directly to the rotor by a stream of ionised particles so as to eliminate the prime mover requirement.

Comment: 1. Yes, you can apply torque to the shaft of a motor and use it to generate power. 2. You could do that, but why would you want to? What advantage would it provide? 3. Then the stream of particles becomes the torque source.

Comment: 1. Usually a huge amount of rotational kinetic energy is stored in the rotor shaft of the prime mover [typically 4-5 times the electrical power output of the generator for a generator with 4% droop]. If the prime mover requirement is eliminated, the entire rotational kinetic energy becomes available at the generator rotor directly. Thus, the conversion losses from mechanical to electromagnetic torque are eliminated.2. Losses arising due to the insulation resistance provided by the air gap can be reduced by providing vacuum.

Comment: 3.Viscous drag losses due to the vorticity of the air in the air gap can be reduced. As a result, more kinetic energy is available to the generator rotor.

Comment: In view of the large size of generators, vacuum, although reducing friction losses, is not very practical.

Comment: But once the the stator-rotor gap is vacuumed & sealed, a small size vacuum pump would be sufficient to remove any air/gases leaking past the seals. We commonly use hydrogen cooling for large size generator rotors with oil sealing, which presents quite a lot of explosion hazards & it is working admirably well. Why wouldn't a vacuum idea work?